# How do I install the Imagick extension on Windows?

Tags: php, pecl

I have used imagemagick concept, so I followed the instructions for Windows given in the below link,

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php

I got

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found.

I need solution for PDF to image or HTML to image conversion using PHP.

Comment: show what you have tried ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php  Please check above url....i followed that instruction.

Comment: Which distribution do you use ?

Comment: Have you done a simple `phpinfo();` to check that it is installed?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Did you follow all the instructions, each step completed successfully, but the extension is not still available? And that page links instructions for Windows and Linux distros. Did you follow them *all*?

Comment: yes..displayed path like  C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Diskeeper Corporation\Diskeeper\

Comment: Hi Paul,  after completed instalation i put this php code <?php
$im = new Imagick();
$im->newPseudoImage(100, 100, "magick:rose");
$im->setImageFormat("png");
$im->roundCorners(5,3);
$type=$im->getFormat();
header("Content-type: $type");
echo $im->getimageblob();
?>  Then run that code  i got error like Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found

Comment: I've edited the question to mention that you use Windows (you should have done it yourself). Now, I don't believe you followed the instructions. You need a C compiler for that and I strongly suspect you don't have one.

Comment: Check that extension directory is correct bin php.ini

Comment: And tcpdf is a better library for HTML to PDF printing

Comment: Does Imagick show up in your phpinfo page?  Did you make sure you edited your php.ini file to load the extension?